# Referencing Field from a Dataset in a Vriable

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating a variable trying to use a field from a dataset, but it's throwing an error. "DATAFields" is the name of the dataset.

```
=Year(Fields!Year.Value, "DATAFields")-9
```

Error:

> The definition of he report is invalid. The Variable expression for
>   the report 'body' refers directly to the  field 'Year' without
>   specifying a dataset aggregate. When the report contains multiple
>   datasets, field references outside of a data region must to contained
>   within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope.

```
Example
02/02/2015 
Output 
2007
```

Please can someone help...

Comment: Please post the complete error message. and include in your question an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a Parameter to reference. and it now works.

```
=Year(Variables!Short_Month.Value)-9
```

In the textbox I used

```
=Variables!v1.Value & " Total is"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in your question you are using a dataset name I assume you are calling dataset1 from dataset2. And you are trying to get the year from that field in dataset1.

This expression is wrong:

```
=Year(Fields!Year.Value, "DATAFields")-9
```

You try this:

```
=First(Fields!Year.Value, "DATAFields")
```

- right click on the expression > Placeholder Properties > Number > Date > Choose your desired date format.

*If ever you are not calling it from another dataset you could just use:

```
=Fields!Year.Value
```

Then repeat how to format your date.

***Note:** There is another way to format your date in your expression but for me this a bit cleaner way.

UPDATE:
You could also try this:

```
=Year(First(Fields!DatePreparedBy.Value, "DSBUser"))-9 & " Total is"
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this. I added the expression to the Variable. I need to use the Variable with some text in a text box. how do I go about formatting the data as yyyy? Example =Variables!v1.Value + " Total is"

Comment: I ran th code without formatting to see what it does. I got error: The Variables(v1) value expression for the report body uses aggregate function First, Last or Previous. These aggregate functions cannot be used in variable value expressions.

Comment: UPDATE: I got the error:  I got error: The Variables(v1) value expression for the report body uses aggregate function First, Last or Previous. These aggregate functions cannot be used in variable value expressions

Comment: I will try this...Tried but same error. There must be something i'm doing wrong. Ideally I would NOT like to add the text in the Variable. I need to use the Variable in my filter elsewhere afterwards.

Comment: Thank you Very much for your help. Appreciated.

Comment: it would be much appreciated if you could upvote my answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. **If your report has more than one dataset, you cannot use the "first()" function in a variable expression.**

I also didn't want to pass the value as a parameter. I ended up creating a calculated field in the same dataset as the data I was trying to reference and that worked for me.